# sympy で cos(1/4π) は、√2/2 と展開されますが、cos(3/4π) は、cos(0.75π) と展開されます。　cos(3/4π) も同様に展開できないでしょうか。

Tags: python, sympy

sympy の version は、1.6.2
python の version は、3.7.4
OS は、windows10 64bit です。

下記、試した結果です。trigsimp が有ってもなくても、同じでした。

```
sympy.trigsimp(cos(0/4*sympy.pi)) -> 1
sympy.trigsimp(cos(1/4*sympy.pi)) -> √2/2
sympy.trigsimp(cos(2/4*sympy.pi)) -> 0
sympy.trigsimp(cos(3/4*sympy.pi)) -> cos(0.75π)
sympy.trigsimp(cos(4/4*sympy.pi)) -> -1
sympy.trigsimp(cos(5/4*sympy.pi)) -> -√2/2
sympy.trigsimp(cos(6/4*sympy.pi)) -> 0
sympy.trigsimp(cos(7/4*sympy.pi)) -> cos(1.75π)
sympy.trigsimp(cos(8/4*sympy.pi)) -> 1
```

となります。cos(3/4π) が-√2/2 と展開されることを期待しています。

式の簡略化は、下記を試みましたが解決しませんでした。
powsimp, trigsimp, logcombine, radsimp,
sympy.simplify, separatevars, collect,
ratsimp, radsimp,rad_rationalize

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `sympy.pi` を先に評価するという方法が考えられます。`sympy.trigsimp(sympy.cos(sympy.pi*3/4))`